# Get environment variable from Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried to get the variable in `docker-compose.yml` like `${NODE_ENV}` but doesn't work.

Also I don't want to send any param on my commands. I have defined already an environment variable on my system and I'd like to take that one from either one of these 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was running `export NODE_ENV=development` again. I was losing this env var every time I was closing the terminal